# Как загрузить картинку из Интернета и показать ее на форме

Tags: java, swing

Получаю адрес изображения со страницы с помощью JSoup.

Нужно загрузить картинку и показать ее на фрейме.

Comment: Не очень понятно как вы картинку будете парсить. Вы имеете ввиду её URL? URL постоянно меняется?

Comment: Да к сожалению урл

Comment: и в чем проблема? Загрузить страницу, найти на ней картинку, получить адрес картинки из тега <img>, загрузить картинку в приложение, показать картинку пользователю. С чем именно у вас проблема?

Comment: С последним пунктом в приложении показать картинку пользователю.

Comment: Приложение у вас на чем (swing, android, awt, swt)?

Comment: Приложение на swing

Answer (score 2):

1. Берем из HTML URL картинки при помощи JSOUP (это вы умеете);
2. Берем картинку при помощи [`ImageIO.read()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read%28java.net.URL%29);
3. Рисуем картинку при помощи [`Graphics.drawImage()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage%28java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver%29)

Можно дополнительно почитать [статью](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) (на английском). Там есть маленький и показательный пример